# Nested .Select() inside of .Where()

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a many-to-many relationship between tables of Games and Genres. During an analysis, i need to get items from Games that match specific criteria.

The problem is, to check for this criteria, i need to analyse genres of this specific game. And linq won't let me do it.

My request now looks like this:

```
var result = GDB.Games.Where((g)=>
  g.GamesToGenres.Select((gtg)=>
    (weights.ContainsKey(gtg.Genre.Name) ? weights[gtg.Genre.Name]:0.0)
  ).Sum() > Threshhold
).ToArray();
```

When I execute it, I receive SQL exception

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Is there a workaround? How can i perform such Select inside of Where?

EDIT: `weights` is a `Dictionary<string, double>`.

EDIT: I was playing with lambdas, and found out a strange thing in their behaviour:
this code won't work, throwing nvarchar to float conversion exception:

```
Func<string, double> getW = (name) => 1;
var t = GDB.Games.Where((g)=>
  g.GamesToGenres.Select((gtg)=>
    getW(gtg.Genre.Name)
  ).Sum() > Threshhold
).ToArray();
```

but this one will work nicely:

```
var t = GDB.Games.Where((g)=>
  g.GamesToGenres.Select((gtg)=>
    1
  ).Sum() > Threshhold
).ToArray();
```

This leads me to conclusion that linq lambdas are *not* usual lambdas. What's wrong with them, then? What are their limitations? What i can and what i can't do inside of them? Why is it ok for me to place a .select call inside of lambda, but not my own call of getW?

RESOLVED. See the answer below. Long story short, C# can't into clojures unless explicitly told so. If anyone knows better answer, i am still confused.

Comment: Where does the "weights" come from ?

Comment: LINQ lambdas *are* usual lambdas, but they are parsed by the Linq-to-SQL engine and converted to SQL. There are things that can't be done in SQL that can be done in pure C# code, and that's where your problem is coming from.

Comment: @siride lambdas are `LambdaExpression` instances when parsed to a `Querable<T>`'s extension methods. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Gusdor: `LambdaExpression` represents the lambda construct, but it isn't, itself, a lambda as lambdas exist in the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you're trying to select something form the dictionary `weights` that exists in your application and not in your DB.  If it was the result of a query to your DB, use the `query.Single(...)` in its place

Comment: huh. It's quite an interesting way to say this using SQLException, never would've thought of that. Is there a way to use custom object inside of a query? this dictionary is constructed using lots of math, and i do not want to implement it in SQL

Comment: not for your purposes.  What you'll need to do is project your results prior to the aggregation and aggregate client side.

Comment: well sir, i did what you deemed impossible. I added it as a separate answer, but in short - i just wrapped everything inside of .Where() into a lambda **that was assigned to a variable, and then passed this variable into .Where()**. And it worked. Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: It's doing what I said you would need to do - `Where<T>( Func<T, bool> )` is an extension on `IEnumerable<T>`, NOT `IQueryable<T>`.  What this means is your solution is enumerating the `DbSet<Game>` `Games`, then applying the filter.  As such, the filtering is occurring client side, where you `weights` dictionary exists.

Comment: ...it is confusing. The whole time i was sure that i was using (Func) overload. I remember wondering why lambda can't be evaluated to var and reading about some Expressions, but i wasn't expecting them there. Thanks a lot, this clears everything up.

Comment: the in-place lambda is actually an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and the LINQ to Entities query provider would try to convert the expression to a SQL statement - which is not currently supported in terms of a dictionary.  A simple `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is a primitive data type is possible, however, by using the `Contains` method.  In essencie, the `weights.Keys.Contains( gtg.Genre.Name )` would work, but you'd have no way to select a value from `weights` in the resulting SQL script

Answer (score 0):

Well, i am confused beyond imagination. The following code works perfectly:

```
Func<Game, bool> predicate = (g) =>
  g.GamesToGenres.Select((gtg) =>
    (weights.ContainsKey(gtg.Genre.Name) ? weights[gtg.Genre.Name] : 0.0)
  ).Sum() > Threshhold;

var t = GDB.Games.Where(predicate).ToArray();
```

careful reader might want to say "Hey! Isn't that the very same code you wrote in the question? You just explicitly assigned it to a variable!", and he will be right. Right now it seems like C# lambda processor is a piece of something, and it creates clojure only when you explicitly declare a lambda. If someone can describe this phenomena to me, i will be gratefull, for right now i am more confused than a newborn baby.

Comment: see comment to my answer - filtering is occurring client side and not at the DB

Answer (score 0):

[LINQ allows](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/719527e6-bf07-47b1-82fa-00b0e3988a34/how-can-i-join-a-database-tables-with-local-datatable-using-linq) you to combine SQL data with local data like (Dictionary, etc.) with one restriction. You need to select data from SQL first. This means your code will work if you replace **GDB.Games.Where** with **GDB.Games.ToList().Where**. You can ask about performance, but you able to select a slice of data like GameId, Genre Name, etc. Then filter out games. Then return end list of full game's info by game ID list.